# How to test laravel 5.6 with mysql 8 docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gitlab-ci-runner, mysql-8.0

Due to new hashing algorithms in **mysql 8** I am unable to successfully run CI tests in **gitlab** against this mysql version.

I believe this applies to other CI engines also.

Let's assume my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is as as simple as that:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
  services:
    - mysql:8.0

  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - composer install
    - php artisan migrate
```

And this is the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I've found different posts, about reconfiguring mysql instance, but this image is official mysql docker, and I believe it should work the same way, across different versions ...

Images from mysql:5.5 to 5.7 didn't introduce any problems, but with mysql:8.0 I get error as stated before...

So far I have not found any solution to get around this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I have managed it to work.

in this case, **mysql service** should be called differently:

```
services:
     - name: mysql:latest
       command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
```